Is there a name for the pair of functions $f(x,y)$ and $f(y,x)$?
The title is self explanatory. For a function of two variables $f(x,y)$ is there a name for the function $f(y,x)$? Certainly, if $f$ is a symmetric function $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$.

Looks like it is the same function $f(\cdot ,\cdot)$ to me. You just apply it to arguments in another way, say, like $x^y$ vs. $y^x$ is the same function of 'raising to a power'.

Not sure if there's a standard name, I would probably call it the reflection over the $x=y$ plane, or just the reflection if no other reflections are being considered.

In the context of functional programming you might call it flip f.

@CiaPan I think OP is actually asking if the relation between these two functions has a name.  There is a uniform mapping $\mathcal N$ such that $\mathcal (N(f))(x, y) = f(y, x)$ for all functions $f$ of two arguments, and OP wants to know if $\mathcal N$ has a standard name, or if there is a name for the symmetric relation that says that $f\sim g$ if $f = \mathcal N(g)$.  This is a reasonable question.

@MJD yes. This is what I'm after.
